# Python - ReportLab Dataframe to PDF

Tags: python, dataframe, pdf, reportlab

Im using a script in python ReportLab to write a data frame data into a PDF file. But I'm getting the following error.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/sbl/script.py", line 343, in <module>
    dataframe_to_pdf(df, 'output2.pdf')
  File "/home/ubuntu/sbl/script.py", line 340, in dataframe_to_pdf
    doc.build(elements)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/reportlab/platypus/doctemplate.py", line 1317, in build
    BaseDocTemplate.build(self,flowables, canvasmaker=canvasmaker)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/reportlab/platypus/doctemplate.py", line 1082, in build
    self.handle_flowable(flowables)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/reportlab/platypus/doctemplate.py", line 961, in handle_flowable
    raise LayoutError(ident)
reportlab.platypus.doctemplate.LayoutError: Flowable <Table@0x7F60BC874B20 2 rows x 2 cols(tallest row 2376)> with cell(0,0) containing
'<Paragraph at 0x7f60bc874be0>Findings'(439.27559055118115 x 2412), tallest cell 2376.0 points,  too large on page 31 in frame 'normal'(439.27559055118115 x 685.8897637795277*) of template 'Later'
```

This is the code that Im using.  Or any other better way to generate the PDF from the data frame?

```py
import textwrap
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet, ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table, TableStyle, Spacer, Paragraph, PageBreak
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont

# Font Path
## Regular
font_path1 = r'fonts/AlbertSans-Regular.ttf'
font_name1 = 'AlbertSans-Regular'
## Bold
font_path2 = r'fonts/AlbertSans-Bold.ttf'
font_name2 = 'AlbertSans-Bold'

pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont(font_name1, font_path1))
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont(font_name2, font_path2))


def dataframe_to_pdf(df, filename):
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(filename, pagesize=A4)
    styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
    styles['Normal'].fontName = 'AlbertSans-Regular'
    styles['Heading1'].fontName = 'AlbertSans-Bold'
    styles['Heading2'].fontName = 'AlbertSans-Bold'
    styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='Link', parent=styles['Normal'], textColor=colors.blue, underline=True))
    table_style = TableStyle([
        ('TEXTCOLOR', (0, 0), (-1, 0), colors.black),
        ('ALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 'LEFT'),
        ('FONTNAME', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 'AlbertSans-Regular'),
        ('FONTSIZE', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 12),
        ('BOTTOMPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 0),
        ('TOPPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 0),
        ('BOTTOMPADDING', (0, 1), (-1, -1), 6),
        ('TOPPADDING', (0, 1), (-1, -1), 6),
        ('FONTNAME', (0, 1), (-1, -1), 'AlbertSans-Regular'),
        ('FONTSIZE', (0, 1), (-1, -1), 10),
        ('ALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'LEFT'),
        ('VALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'MIDDLE'),
        ('TEXTCOLOR', (0, 1), (-1, -1), colors.black),
        ('GRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 1, colors.black)
    ])
    elements = []

    # First page heading
    first_page_heading = Paragraph('Details of Failed Check:', styles['Heading1'])
    elements.append(first_page_heading)

#    result = df.groupby(['DESCRIPTION', 'RISK', 'STATUS', 'SEVERITY', 'REMEDIATION_RECOMMENDATION_TEXT', 'REMEDIATION_RECOMMENDATION_URL', 'CHECK_ID']).agg({'STATUS_EXTENDED': ',    '.join, 'RESOURCE_ID': ',    '.join}).reset_index()
    result = df.groupby(['DESCRIPTION', 'RISK', 'STATUS', 'SEVERITY', 'CHECK_ID']).agg({
    'STATUS_EXTENDED': lambda x: ', '.join(x.astype(str)),
    'RESOURCE_ID': lambda x: ', '.join(x.astype(str))
}).reset_index()

    result_csv = df.groupby(['DESCRIPTION', 'RISK', 'STATUS', 'SEVERITY', 'REGION', 'REMEDIATION_RECOMMENDATION_TEXT', 'REMEDIATION_RECOMMENDATION_URL', 'CHECK_ID']).agg({
    'STATUS_EXTENDED': lambda x: ', '.join(x.astype(str)),
    'RESOURCE_ID': lambda x: ', '.join(x.astype(str))
}).reset_index()
    csv_fail = result[result['STATUS'] == 'FAIL']
    csv_fail.to_csv('Failed_result.csv',index=False)
    # Rows where STATUS is 'FAIL'
    df_fail = result[result['STATUS'] == 'FAIL']

    # Extract unique severities from the filtered dataframe
    severities = df_fail['SEVERITY'].unique()

    for index, severity in enumerate(severities):
        # Filter rows based on severity
        filtered_df = df_fail[df_fail['SEVERITY'] == severity]

        # Take one row as column names
        column_names_row = filtered_df.head(1)

        # Extract the values for column names
        description_col = str(column_names_row['DESCRIPTION'].values[0])
        risk_col = str(column_names_row['RISK'].values[0])
        findings_col = str(column_names_row['STATUS_EXTENDED'].values[0])
        resources_col = str(column_names_row['RESOURCE_ID'].values[0])
        #remediation_col = str(column_names_row['REMEDIATION_RECOMMENDATION_TEXT'].values[0])
        #remediation_url_col = str(column_names_row['REMEDIATION_RECOMMENDATION_URL'].values[0])
        check_id_col = str(column_names_row['CHECK_ID'].str.replace('_', ' ').str.title().values[0])

        # Add the column names to the rows
        data_rows = []
        data_rows.append([
            Paragraph('Description', styles['Heading2']),
            Paragraph(description_col, styles['Normal'])
        ])
```